# Drop down list selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

Im trying to use a drop down list whit selenium :

```py
browser.get('https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru')
day = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/select'))
dayDD=Select(day)
dayDD.select_by_index(3)
```

but i always get this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/select"}
```

I dont know why it can't find xpath since i get it same way i get all my other xpaths

Answer (score 0):

could you attach DOM page screen with list of elements?

At this stage I see 2 posibilities:

**- Elements are not loaded**

Use implicit or explicit wait : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/waits-in-selenium-python/?ref=rp

**- Xpath is not correct**

Maybe learn how to use relative path : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_relative_path.htm

Comment: You can check DOM here : https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru

Comment: Maybe try this relative xpath 

//div[@data-test-id='birth-date__day']/select[@class='c01200']